# Typescript: Inferring value types on a per-key basis

Tags: typescript, mapped-types, conditional-types

I have a lot of code that generates algebra problems. I'd like each problem generator to be able to specify the kind of values it needs randomly generated, and then get those values with their appropriate types. (Doing it this way allows other neat things like non-random problem specification.)

I'm struggling with the last part --- lining up the output types with the input specification.

Here's an example of the trouble:

```
type Field<V> = {
    generate(): V;
}

type BoolField = Field<boolean>;
function randomB(): BoolField {
    return {
        generate() {
            return Math.random() > 0.5;
        }
    }
}

type IntField = Field<number>;
function randomI(i: number): IntField {
    return {
        generate() {
            return Math.round(Math.random() * i);
        }
    };
}

type Fields<K extends string> = {
    [key in K]: BoolField | IntField;
}

type Values<K extends string> = {
    [key in K]: Fields<K>[key] extends Field<infer V> ? V : never;
};

/** Turn each field into the random value it specifies */
function sample<K extends string>(fields: Fields<K>): Values<K> {
    const values: Partial<Values<K>> = {};
    Object.keys(fields).forEach(k => {
        values[k] = fields[k as K].generate();
    });
    return values as Required<Values<K>>;
}

const testFields: Fields<'a' | 'b' | 'i'> = {
    a: randomB(),
    b: randomB(),
    i: randomI(10),
};

const testValues = sample(testFields);
```

The heart of it is the conditional type in `Values`, which I was hoping would infer the type that's returned by the `Field.generate` function.

But when I look at the type of `testValues.a`, for example, it isn't `boolean`, but rather `number | boolean`. It's the same for every field in `testValues`.

I'm not totally clear on why the output types get mixed together like this. It seems the compiler should have visibility into each field type separately. But apparently it doesn't. What am I missing?

Comment: You are giving `sample` the type of `Fields<"a" | "b" | "i">`, which itself does not differentiate between `BoolField` or `IntField`. Your function cannot "undo" this and magically get the types for each key from this. Consider removing the type annotation entirely, or in TS 4.9+, use `satisfies`.

Comment: Removing the annotation from `testFields`, the code still runs, with the same result. I was interested in using `satisfies` from 4.9, but it seems not to be allowed in argument position---but I need a function call that all of my problem generators can take advantage of. I guess I just misunderstood the mapped and conditional types docs---the `key in K` iterator and the indexed lookups based on `key` really make it seem as if per-key type information could be propagated, but I guess that's not true

Comment: I've also attempted a design where I have separate key types for bools and ints, but keep them in the same record. The ergonomics would still be great, but the compiler can't infer which keys belong to which type, even though it's actually unambiguous since they map to different field types.